# reference to DOM element in Vue,js component computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Inside a Vue component computed property. How can I get a reference to the DOM element this method initiated by?

for instance:

```html
<template>
  <img :src="getUrl" class="image1"/>
  <img :src="getUrl" class="image2"/>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      getUrl() {
        //reference to the DOM element and get the className..
        switch(className) {
          case 'image1':
          //code..
          break
          case 'image2':
          //code...
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

NOTE:
I was printing the 'this' inside the method and couldn't find nothing that can help me over here....

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use method instead of computed property.

```
methods : {
  getUrl(className){
    switch(className) {
      case 'image1':
        //code..
        break
      case 'image2':
        //code...
        break
    }
  }
}

<template>
  <img :src="getUrl('image1')" class="image1"/>
  <img :src="getUrl('image2')" class="image2"/>
</template>
```

Comment: methods in Vue.js has it's own issues... the cache thing is a real downside. Ill try it anyway...

Comment: You can make custom image component and use params instead.
For example <my-img :class="image1"> and use computed properties there